# Flutter re-login it does not directs to the intended home page

Tags: android-studio, flutter, logout, bottomnavigationview

Flutter Logout directs to login page but after re-login it does not redirects to the intended home page.

I have used the below navigation for login

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Home()));
```

My app is consist of three bottom navigation bar.Home Page is in second navigation bar. I have to logout from third navigation bar.

I have used the below code for logout

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/Login', (_) => false);
```

Also i have tried the codes too

```
 Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/Login");


Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login(),), (Route route) => false);
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Are you try to Shared Preference?

Comment: did you try `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Login');`

Comment: @AhmedKhattab yep.. but still face the issue.

Comment: @HardikTalaviya did u mean that i used shared preference? if yes.. yep i have used it

Comment: @SanaAfreen Yes save your login key and open screen as per key set in preference,are you try this?

Comment: @HardikTalaviya Can u be more specific..

Comment: @SanaAfreen check my answer if it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use shared preference to store as login key and check if it is true then go to main screen or else redirect to login screen.

First of all add shared preference dependency in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
```

**SplashScreen.dart**

This is first screen where we are check that if **isLogin is true** then go to **HomeScreen** or **else** redirect to **LoginScreen**

```
_autoLogin() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  if (!prefs.containsKey('isLogin')) {
    prefs.setBool('isLogin', false);
  }
  if (prefs.getBool('isLogin')) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        ));
  } else {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        ));;
  }
}
```

**LoginScreen.dart**

```
_setIsLogin() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isLogin', true);
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
      ));
}


MaterialButton(
  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
  onPressed: () {
    _setIsLogin();
  },
  child: Text("LOGIN",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: style.copyWith(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 18.0)),
),
```

**HomeScreen.dart**

Set **isLogin** as **false** when click on **Logout**

```
_logout() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isLogin', false);
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
      ));
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

This is my splash screen

```
    class SplashState  extends State<SplashScreen>{
  bool isLogged = false;
  startTime(){
    return new Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), navigateUser);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStoredValue();
    }


  void getStoredValue() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('isLoggin')) {
      prefs.setBool('isLoggin', false);
      print("login set to False");
    }


    isLogged = prefs.getBool('isLoggin');
    print("Status in splash -----------$isLogged");
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return  Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient:LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: <Color>[
             colorStyle.splashPink,
             colorStyle.splashOrange,
            ],
          )
        ),
        child: Center(
          child:  Image.asset("assets/images/splash_logo.png", height: 85.0),
        ),
    );
  }

  void navigateUser() {
    if (isLogged == true) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Home()));
    }
    else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Login()));
    }
    }
}
```

Logout

```
     void logoutUser()async{
    LogoutUser objLog = await createPost(logoutUrl,body);
    if(objLog.statusCode == 10000){
      print(("response is $resp"));
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setBool('isLoggin', false);
       Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
    }
    else showToast(objLog.message, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
```